# Tooltip doesn't set inside a modal

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I'm trying to set a tooltip inside a modal, but it only show the title.

[image]

I've already tried set tooltip when the modal is shown but nothing happens.

```
$(ele).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

The button is like that:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-select2" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" data-placement="top" title="Selecionar todos"><i class="fas fa-check-double"></i></button>
```

So far, even the title shown up.

So, I have a function that every time that modal is open, it does a foreach to find these buttons (to do another action) but I inserted again the `title`, `data-original-title` and `tooltip`, like this:

```
$('modal').find('.btn-select2').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('title', 'Selecionar Todos');
    $(this).attr('data-original-title', 'Selecionar Todos');
    $(this).data('placement', 'top');
    $(this).tooltip();
});
```

After that, the title starts to show like the image, but no success with the tooltip. Any solution?

EDIT:
Here's the HTML of the button that is inserted inside the modal

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Cargos</label>
    <div class="input-group input-group-select2">
        <select name="charges[]" class="form-control select2" multiple>
            @foreach($charges as $charge)
            <option value="{{$charge->id}}">{{$charge->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>    
        <div class="inpt-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-select2" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" data-placement="top" title="Selecionar todos"><i class="fas fa-check-double"></i></button>
        </div>    
    </div> 
</div>
```

In the end of the document, I put:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
    $('.btn-select2').tooltip();
});
```

And have some modals, that use a function to open, and it's in these modals that the title shown up but the tooltip doesn't. In the other modals that just use `data-toggle` to open, even the title is shown. Here is the code of the function:

```
const modalUpdate = function(obj, ele, hasSub = false) {
    $(ele).find('.btn-select2').each(function() {
        var button = this;
        var changeHeight = function () {
            var newHeight = $(button).parent().parent()[0].children[1].children[0].children[0].clientHeight;
            button.style = 'height: ' + (newHeight + 2) + 'px!important';
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            changeHeight();
        }, 200);
        $(this).attr('title', 'Selecionar Todos');
        $(this).attr('data-original-title', 'Selecionar Todos');
        $(this).data('placement', 'top');
        $(this).tooltip();
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: please provide whole code that you tried

Comment: Have you checked the z-index of the tooltip element?  It *might* be appearing behind the dialog (but then I would expect the title to not appear) - but worth checking.

Comment: `$('modal')` - unlikely to find anything - did you mean `$('.modal')` ?

Comment: Always test your selectors in the browser console, it `console.log($('modal').find('.btn-select2').length)` - bet it shows `0`.